# Laravel HAS MANY/BELONGS TO relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to join two tables with laravel relationship, but I've gotten stuck.

I have 2 MySSL tables

```
table strans
    + id
    + trans_code
    + trans_description

table step
    + step_id
    + step_trans_code
    + step_proc_sequence
```

My models look like this:

```
class Strans extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hc_strans';
    protected $fillable = [
        'trans_code', 'trans_description', 'trans_sk_code'
    ];
    public function step()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sstep::class, 'step_trans_code', 'trans_code');
    }
}
 
 
 class Sstep extends Model
 {
    protected $table = 'hc_sstep';
    protected $fillable = [
        'step_trans_code', 'step_proc_sequence'
    ];
    public function transCode()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo(Strans::class, 'trans_code', 'step_trans_code');
    }
 }
```

At the step controller, I called the relationship:

```
$step = Sstep::with('transCode')->get();
```

The table data have all the relationship values. But when I try the relationship, transCode variable returns a null value.
I tried with manual query, it's no problem.

```
"data": [
    {
        "step_id": 8,
        "step_trans_code": "MUT",
        "step_proc_sequence": 80,
        "trans_code": null
    }
]
```

Am I doing it wrong in the relationship?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at us when you're asking us to help you solve **your** problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel has a naming convention, for example in belongs to the relationship it will consider the foreign key as stran_id, so define the foreign key explicitly.

```
public function transCode()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Strans::class, 'step_trans_code', 'trans_code');
}

$step = Sstep::with('transCode')->get();
```

Comment: i change to this:
public function transCode()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Strans::class, 'trans_code', 'step_trans_code');
    }

it's still the same

Comment: okay you have specfied it wrong, updating my answer

Comment: Oh, i have to define it explicitly..

Comment: can you please specify the primary and foreign keys ?

Comment: PK : id and step_id
FK: trans_code and step_trans_code

Comment: you mean strans table primary key is id ?

Comment: return $this->belongsTo(Strans::class, 'step_trans_code', 'trans_code');
 this work fine

Comment: aah okay then are taking trans_code as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Sstep extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'hc_sstep';
   public function transCode()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(Strans::class, 'step_trans_code', 'trans_code');
   }
}
```

Comment: What is this? Your solution? Or more details about your problem? Please clarify.

Answer (score -1):

another answer, you can easily do the following without the `with`:

```
$step = Sstep::first();
$transCode = $setp->transCode;
```

Comment: Well, what about Eager loading? Your Query will create N + 1 queries if not used eager loading.

Comment: As what I understood you want the relation so you should do it like that but if you don't know of you are going to use the relation or not then you should use with

Comment: first of all, I did not asked the question.
second his relationship was incorrectly formed.
and then you statement of the comment, I does not matter you know or not know, you need related data then you will have to eager load your model if not it will have serious loading time and optimization issues with higher amount of data.